# i cant run my python code using kivy for making a gui app

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, python-3.9

**so basically i cant run it it just says what is under here, i used python kivy for gui.it always says this even on different projects.

```
 [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
  File "D:\anacondaprogramfiles\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "D:\anacondaprogramfiles\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

.**

i tried alot of stuff i uninstalled python download it from diferent places uninsalled kivy tried other ide PLEASE HELP
I USE WINDOWS 11
PYTHON 3.9
ITS BEEN 2DAYS LIKE THAT

Answer (score 0):

Based on

```
PS D:\>  d:; cd 'd:\\'; & 'D:\anacondaprogramfiles\python.exe' 'c:\Users\khale\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '50433' '--' 'd:\# base Class of your App inherits from t.py'
```

the file with your code is named `# base Class of your App inherits from t.py`. That's... very unusual and apparently doesn't work.

Rename your file to something simpler, such as `my_app.py`, and try again.

Comment: thanks,i tried to do this but it didnt work

Comment: Please update your original post with the results of running your program with a more conventional filename, anyway.

Comment: sorry but ididnt understand what to do